# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite' when running django app online in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

This is my log file:

`2020-08-18T18:58:09.806459+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'`

**Yet my Django app is running locally.**
*The app is being deployed on web but on execution its giving error.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be related to your project structure and wrong command in the `Procfile`. For example, I once had a project where the `manage.py` file was not in the root, but one level deeper under the `project_name/`. If that's the case for you, you can try using something like this in your `Procfile`.

```
web: sh -c 'cd project_name && gunicorn project_name.wsgi'
```

The crucial part is that it executes command that first enters the folder and then runs the usual command.

If you can, please share your project structure and the current Procfile command, so we can verify.

Comment: Thanks its on the server now .. but there is a new error when I am logining in my web app: **ProgrammingError at /login/** `relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user...` **Exception Location:** `/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute` **Exception Value:** `relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user... `

Comment: Don't use comments for another problem and ask a new question.